# Converting shapefile to WKB after v.clean

Tags: qgis, shapefile, postgresql, convert, well-known-binary

I've been trying to get to through this by reading manuals, but I can't seem to understand what I'm doing.

I have source data with overlaps that exist in a table with associated WKBs (SRID 4326).  I eliminated these overlaps using the v.clean tool in the processing toolbox panel.  The output that I receive is a shapefile and at first glance seems to overlap perfectly (the overlaps are resolved when run against the topology checker).

[image: Seems Good]

When I run Import that shapefile into PG as a table via Shapefile Loader 2.1 plug-in and compare the visualization it is a very different scale and location as shown in the image below.

[image: Considerably Larger]

The original image is pictured on the right.  Perhaps I'm approaching this problem the wrong way, but it seems simple enough to grasp what I'm trying to do. Ideally I maintain the same dimensions the above image but modify the underlying source data.